# no index.lighttpd.html in var/www/html

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, lighttpd

I would like to remotely control Raspberry Pi 3B+ through flask and lighttpd.

I would like to control the RC car through the web.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install flask

sudo apt-get install lighttpd

sudo apt autoremove
```

After the above commands, the `/var/www/html` folder is created. Also, `lighttpd.conf` is created in `/etc/lighttpd/`. However, `index.lighttpd.html` is not created in `/var/www/html`. So even if I turn on localhost on the web, lighttpd does not come out.

I have tried a lot of things. I tried again several times after initializing the sd card. I received the lighttpd file directly through the 'git clone' without using the pip, but the result was the same.

- sudo apt install lighttpd lighttpd-doc

sudo apt-get install python3-flask

- In addition, all the above commands were used. The lighttpd.conf file also seems to have no problem.

```
server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>" > /var/www/html/index.html`
It's your web server instance.  You need to configure the content to be served.  I'd recommend reading the lighttpd docs on https://wiki.lighttpd.net/